# I am using tinyMCE mceInsertContent why it's remove the front slash?

Tags: c#, tinymce

This is my code

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<a href="<ers:redirectURL>https//yahoo.com</a>">xxx</a>');
```

but the output look like this

```
<ers:redirectURL>https/yahoo.com</a>
```

only 1 front slash? https/yahoo.com

I think the cause of problem was `<ers:redirectURL>`
But I need to put this tag `<ers:redirectURL>` between the URL.

Please help.

---

Anyway I got the answer. just add this in tinyMCE.init

convert_urls: false

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be, with ':' in the url, and only one `</a>` (not sure it will work anyway, with the odd resulting url ) :

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<a href="<ers:redirectURL>https://yahoo.com">xxx</a>');
```

Also, to your tiny_mce configuration, add `convert_urls : false` , and set

```
'relative_urls : false'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. still the same result